# Translate name dayOfWeek and month in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I use Google Chart and i want to change name for day of week, month and another calendar data to other language.

```
google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['annotatedtimeline']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAllChart);
```

Current language is English but i want change to Polish.

I tried that way:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['annotatedtimeline'], 'language': 'ja'});
```

but when adding above code then chart is no showing.

[Current view chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlQb9.png)

Comment: show us the full code

Comment: are you still setting the callback --> `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAllChart);`